# Trying to get Postres and Postgis running in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.1, rails-postgresql

I am completely new to Postgresql, Postgis, and SQL and have a little bit of Rails knowledge. I am trying to get an existing app going on my local and am currently receiving the following messages when running a rake task to set up my database.

```
Blane-Cordess-MacBook:ajungo blanecordes$ rake postgres:create_postgis_template --trace
(in /Users/blanecordes/ajungo)
** Invoke postgres:create_postgis_template (first_time)
** Execute postgres:create_postgis_template
Enter your postgres username: blane
Password for user blane: 
psql (9.2.1, server 9.1.4)
WARNING: psql version 9.2, server version 9.1.
     Some psql features might not work.
You are now connected to database "template1" as user "blane".
psql:assets/sql/postgis_template_osx.sql:2: ERROR:  permission denied to create database
psql:assets/sql/postgis_template_osx.sql:6: ERROR:  permission denied for relation      pg_database
psql:assets/sql/postgis_template_osx.sql:7: \connect: FATAL:  database   "template_postgis" does not exist
```

My postgis_template_osx.sql file is the following:

```
\c template1
CREATE DATABASE template_postgis WITH template = template1;

-- set the 'datistemplate' record in the 'pg_database' table for
-- 'template_postgis' to TRUE indicating its a template
  UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate = TRUE WHERE datname = 'template_postgis';
\c template_postgis
CREATE LANGUAGE plpgsql ;
\i /usr/local/Cellar/postgis/2.0.1/share/postgis/postgis.sql;
\i /usr/local/Cellar/postgis/2.0.1/share/postgis/spatial_ref_sys.sql;
-- 1.5.2


-- in a production environment you may want to
-- give role based permissions, but granting all for now
GRANT ALL ON geometry_columns TO PUBLIC;
GRANT ALL ON spatial_ref_sys TO PUBLIC;

-- vacuum freeze: it will guarantee that all rows in the database are
-- "frozen" and will not be subject to transaction ID wraparound
-- problems.
VACUUM FREEZE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PostgreSQL [ROLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrole.html) *blane* does not have permission to create databases. Either [ALTER](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterrole.html) *blane* and add the CREATEDB option or use an existing administrator role that has that capability.

```
postgres=# ALTER ROLE blane WITH CREATEDB;
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! Would you be able to provide me an example of what this looks like from the command line?

Comment: See edit. You'll need to be logged in as a superuser who can CREATEROLE, usually *postgres* or the user who installed PostgreSQL.

Comment: ah gotcha, this is very helpful thanks. In my database.yml file I have  development database named and a username specified however since I cant create the database I am a bit stuck on where to start. Dont I need to create the database before I can go in as a superuser and add a role with? or is there a way to go into my postgres console and create this role which will be for all my apps going forward? sorry such a newb!